# Calling method of WCF Service that is hosted in IIS consumed in a Windows Service but the Service not starting

Tags: asp.net, wcf, windows-services, wcf-binding

Can you please advice why I am not able to start my Windows Service. 
As soon as I start it stops immediately giving me the error that no job to do.

Here is the code:

```
 namespace BulkEmailWindowsService
 {
     public class EmailService : ServiceBase 
     {     
         public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

         public EmailService()
         {
           // Name the Windows Service
             ServiceName = "WCFWindowsBulkEmailService";
         }

         public static void Main()
         {
             ServiceBase.Run(new EmailService()); //-------- Stops right here..
         }


         // Start the Windows service.
         protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
         {
             if (serviceHost != null)
             {
                 serviceHost.Close();
             }

             try
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Testing 1");
                 System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                 serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestBulkEmailService.IBulkEmailService));

                 serviceHost.Open();

                 Console.WriteLine("Testing 1");
                 string logBaseDirectory = "C:\\BulkEmailPrototype\\BulkEmailWindowsService\\BulkEmailWindowsService\\Logs\\BulkEmailWindowsService";
                 int loggingLevel = int.Parse("5");
                 int maximumLogFileSize = int.Parse("2");
                 AppLogger.TraceInfo("Initialization(): Reading configuration settings from config file...");
                 AppLogger.Init(logBaseDirectory, 0, loggingLevel, "WCFBulkEmail.log", maximumLogFileSize);
                 AppLogger.TraceInfo("Bulk Email Processing Service is starting....");

                 using (BulkEmailWindowsService.TestBulkEmailService.BulkEmailServiceClient wfc1 = new BulkEmailWindowsService.TestBulkEmailService.BulkEmailServiceClient())
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         AppLogger.TraceInfo("Database and Email Processing starting....");
                         BulkEmailDTOList result1 = new BulkEmailDTOList();
                         result1 = wfc1.GetBulkEmailInfo(1);
                         AppLogger.TraceInfo("Database and Email Processing done....");
                     }
                     catch
                     {
                         AppLogger.TraceInfo("Error in processing Database and Email....");
                     }

                 }

                 serviceHost.Close();
                 serviceHost = null;
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 // Log the exception.
                 Console.WriteLine("Error in ONStart ");
                 AppLogger.TraceInfo("Error in OnStart of Bulk Email Processing Service....");
             }

         }

         protected override void OnStop()
         {
             if (serviceHost != null)
             {
                 serviceHost.Close();
                 serviceHost = null;
             }
         }

     }
 }
```

Here is my app.config file:

```
   <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBulkEmailService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
           openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
           allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
           maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
           messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
           useDefaultWebProxy="true">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
             maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
           <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
             <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
               realm="" />
             <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
           </security>
         </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
     </bindings>
     <client>
       <endpoint address="http://localhost/TestBulkEmailService/TestBulkEmailService.svc/BulkEmailService"
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IBulkEmailService"
         contract="TestBulkEmailService.IBulkEmailService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IBulkEmailService" />
     </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
   <startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
   </startup>
 </configuration>
```

Please note that the WCF Service that is hosted on IIS is running fine and I tested it using a Web App Client. Since I need to run this service constantly on its own (to send emails for bunch of rows from db) hence I am trying to put it in a Windows service with Start and stop. If you know of any other method that is simpler and can do the same please let me know.

this is what I have in my installer

```
namespace BulkEmailWindowsService
{

  // Provide the ProjectInstaller class which allows 
  // the service to be installed by the Installutil.exe tool
  [RunInstaller(true)]
  public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
  {
     private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
     private ServiceInstaller service;

     public ProjectInstaller()
     {
        process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        service = new ServiceInstaller();
        service.ServiceName = "WCFWindowsBulkEmailService";
        Installers.Add(process);
        Installers.Add(service);
     }
  }
 }
```

So is this not right? I am confused where Main will come.

Comment: Anything in event viewer, or in wherever `AppLogger` writes?

Comment: @Internal Server Error - how do I check the event viewer? I tried looking at the Application log but there is nothing. AppLogger is also not writing anything since it is not going that far

Comment: It seems to be erroring out in the Main itself.

Comment: Oh, sorry - missed your comment. Try Debugger.Break() in the constructor and step from there.

Comment: When you say Constructor do you mean under Main()? I am new to .net and WCF and so still don't have the hang of the acronyms.

Comment: I mean `public EmailService()` - incidentally, aren't you missing an `InitializeComponent();` call there?

Comment: I tried to put that under EmailService but it is showing me as error i.e. red line under it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you Main method.

```
private static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new WindowsService()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex.Message)); // if you have a logger?
    }
}
```

Implementation of windows service should look something like this:

```
public partial class WindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null;

    public WindowsService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (myServiceHost != null)
        {
            myServiceHost.Close();
        }
        myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof (EmailService));
        myServiceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (myServiceHost != null)
        {
            myServiceHost.Close();
            myServiceHost = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Question. I should still have the Main under the  EmailService class in BulkEmailWindowsService namespace. Is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error - I am still stuck. It says it cannot start due to class type. For some reason I am not seeing my IMplementation class in TestBulkEmailService.BulkEmailService in ServiceHost. What is wrong?